# Coproduct in the FdHilb category

Tags: category-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Consider the **FdHilb** category i.e. the category of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces that is important especially in the quantum mechanics.

I have some trouble with identification of coproduct in the category. What is it? Any help, hints are welcome.

Edit: The original question incorrectly identified the tensor product as the categorial product. It is very important in the quantum mechanics because it is used to describe compound systems. It will be also fine to get a categorial construction for the tensor product if it is possible

Comment: Tensor product is not the product, at least in the category of finite dimensional vector spaces. Can you clarify what are the maps in your category?

Comment: As I understood the morphisms in the category are the linear maps (between different Hilber spaces) that preserve the structure i.e. such that $f(c_1 a_1 + c_2 a_2) = c_1 f(a_1) + c_2 f(a_2)$ where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the features of **FdHilb** (the cateogry of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces) is that it possesses finite biproducts. A [biproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct) of a finite collection of objects is both a product and a coproduct.

In **FdHilb** the construction that is both a product and a coproduct is *direct sum* of Hilbert spaces, not tensor product. According to the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces), tensor product is not a categorical product: there are not natural maps from a tensor product of two spaces to the two spaces separately, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understood it is not possible to find any categorial construction for the tensor product. It is very strange for me especially because the tensor product is so important for the theory application and without it the categorial view on the quantum mechanic will be incomplete

Comment: @Ivan - Nature is not a good categorist ;-)

Comment: @Ivan According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Universal_property), the tensor product $H_1\otimes H_2$ represents the covariant functor $K \mapsto \mathsf{HS}(H_1,H_2;K)$ where the latter is the set of Hilbert-Schmidt maps from $H_1\times H_2$ to $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! It is not at all clear what the morphisms in $\text{FdHilb}$ should be. If you want them to be all linear maps, then the category you end up with is not really a category of Hilbert spaces, and in fact is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional complex vector spaces; in other words this choice of morphism effectively forgets the inner product.

You could ask for the morphisms to be unitary maps or isometries, which does take the inner product into account, but this choice of morphism is very restrictive and hardly any categorical constructions exist in this category.

The "correct" thing to do appears to be to regard $\text{FdHilb}$ as something more complicated than a category: it is really a [dagger category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger+category) where the dagger is given by taking adjoints and this is somehow crucial to understanding its categorical nature. I do not really understand how "dagger category theory" is supposed to work, and in particular how to adjust the notion of limits and colimits to take the dagger into account.